# I got this error while deploying on Kadena mainnet

Tags: pact-lang

Error HTTP response (Status {statusCode = 400, statusMessage = ""}):"Validation failed for hash "-bcsjpIuk6BpfuynRHeQsXRvxYP7BtizDeeZVt-8e44": Attempt to buy gas failed with: : Failure: Tx Failed: Account name does not conform to the min length requirement: "

Comment: including the crux of the error would be a better title for the question, smt like "Account name does not conform to the min length" instead of "this error"

Answer (score 0):

You can't leave the "sender" field blank. The "sender" field tells Kadena chainweb which coin account is being used to pay gas. It should be an account with some funds on the chain where you are deploying on.

It's recommended to test deployments on testnet. Use the faucet to obtain some test kda.